# How to identify if a text is HTML or not? (in PHP)

Tags: php, html, text, htmlpurifier

I want to read text entries from a database, some of which are actually HTML entries, others are just plain text that might contain HTML markup which should be displayed as text.

Those that are plain text should then be converted to HTML, by first calling PHP's `htmlspecialchars()` function and then running the result through HTMLPurifier.

Or in other words, I'm looking for some tips on how to implement the isHTML() function:

```
$text = getTextFromDatabase();
if (!isHTML($text)) {
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
}
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($text);
```

So for example following text would be run through `htmlspecialchars`:

```
The <p> tag of HTML has to be followed by a </p> tag to end the paragraph.
```

And following text would not be run through `htmlspecialchars`:

```
<p>These are few lines of HTML.</p>
<div>There might be multiple independent</div>
<p>but valid HTML blocks in it.</p>
```

It seems like there should already be an `isHTML()` function out there, but I just can't happen to find it and I don't want to reinvent the wheel :-). Maybe it's even possible to do this with some kind of HTMLPurifier settings?

Note that, if the HTML code is buggy, this should be handled by HTMLPurifier and the code should not be run through `htmlspecialchars`. :-) Like for example having an opening `<p>` tag when there really should be a closing `</p>` tag in the HTML code.

Any help is appreciated, thanks already :-),
Robert.

Comment: Both are HTML snippets for a machine, I'm having a hard time following your logic to determine which should be encoded & which shouldn't, unless you want to write an artifical intelligence that can logically interpret the text and then knows the difference...

Comment: what's the difference between *"actually HTML entries"* and *"plain text that might contain HTML markup"* ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can only check for chars specific for html in string

```
function is_html($string)
{
  return preg_match("/<[^<]+>/",$string,$m) != 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, but have to extended it a little. Using `/^\s*<\s*\w+\d?\s*>/` to match opening tags at the beginning and `/<\s*\/?\s*\w+\d?\s*>\s*$/` to match closing tags at the end of a line (allowing the mistake of forgetting to type the `/` character). Then I can count how many lines are enclosed within a block of an opening and a closing tag ("tagged blocks"), not allowing empty/blank lines. Dividing the number of lines in tagged blocks by the total number of lines without blank lines then should give an estimate of how likely it is to have HTML-text. :-)

Comment: This solution will return positive false if html tags are invalid. You can check here https://regex101.com/r/VQ4wvQ/1/

Answer (score 15):

You can try to use this function

```
function isHTML($string){
    return ($string != strip_tags($string));
}
```

Comment: does not work when $string contains &

Answer (score 9):

Consider this logic:
If a valid html text is detected by htmlentities then the input text and the output text from htmlentities are different. So:

```
function isHTML($text){
   $processed = htmlentities($text);
   if($processed == $text) return false;
   return true; 
}
```

I hope this works for you

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, since it can also differentiate between HTML and XML.

Comment: This function is not able to tell if a string is HTML. See for example 
`isHTML('A => B means if A is true then B is also true; if A is false then nothing is said about B.')`
returns an incorrect `true`.
The only thing it does is telling if a string contains characters that can be converted to HTML entities or not.

Answer (score 5):

If only purpose is to detect that string contains any html tags or not. No matter tags are valid or not then you can try this:

```
function is_html($string) {
  // Check if string contains any html tags.
  return preg_match('/<\s?[^\>]*\/?\s?>/i', $string);
}
```

You can verify this here https://regex101.com/r/2g7Fx4/4

Comment: This is an improvement over @JTC's answer above with more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking if we can compare the striptagged version of string with the original. If they differ - then there have been something to strip. This guy proposes the same thing: https://subinsb.com/php-check-if-string-is-html